# Eclipse won't start after Mac failed to load OS

Tags: eclipse, macos

So, my Mac (OS X El Capitan ver. 10.11) suddenly was so slow that day, to the point sometimes iTunes was lagging in playing a song. Then I restarted it. Just about 2-3 hours, it slowed down again, so I restarted it again.

After that, my mac stucked on the page with gray Apple and loading bar below, the screen when the OS is loaded. After getting into safe mode once, finally I could go to the desktop normally, but my mac still lagging here and there abnormally.

Then, I tried to start Eclipse, and it won't start. It said "An error occurred", and tell me to see the log. Here's the said log: https://jpst.it/IPls

I've tried some suggestions I found and none of these work, the same error log persists:

- clean start using `-clean`
- erase `.metadata` on workspace
- erase `.lock` on workspace
- update to El Capitan `10.11.5` (which just a blind attempt, because Eclipse ran perfectly fine before)

In case it's related, when I back-up my projects after this happened (the first time I succeed to reach desktop), one of my projects always failed to be copy-pasted (it's not even a cut or move), which is the project I actively working on when the OS slowed down.

Does anyone have any idea what have happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the log you have:

```
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error reading zip file
```

and

```
java.lang.LinkageError: Error reading class bytes: com.ibm.icu.impl.UBiDiProps
```

which suggests your Eclipse installation files have been damaged rather than the workspace. I would try doing a clean install of Eclipse.